# Android - chronometer start and stop

Tags: android

I want to create a chronometer which I can start and stop with one button. With my code below I just get a nullpointer exception. How can I avoid it, or set the two functions to the button anyway?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  Chronometer focus;
  Button start, stop, reset;
  long timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - focus.getBase();
  int x;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timeElapsed = x;
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);       
    focus = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(x == 0){
            focus.start();
            }

            if(x != 0){
            focus.stop();    
            }
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail! Maybe the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using variables before they are initialized. 'focus' and 'x' are used before they are initialized. Use this code instead to avoid nullpointer exception:

```
     public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  Chronometer focus;
  Button start, stop, reset;
  long timeElapsed = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);       
    focus = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    // to get the elapsed time use setonChronometerTickListener
    focus.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
             timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - focus.getBase();
         }
    });
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(timeElapsed == 0){
            focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            focus.start();
            }

            if(timeElapsed != 0){
        timeElapsed = 0;
            focus.stop();    
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: It seems to work, but I can't make it stop counting by re clicking the button

Comment: It will stop only when x is not equal to 0, so assign a new value to x other than 0 before reclicking to stop it.

Comment: But isn't x unequal to 0 when it was counting, is it?

Comment: how often are you increasing the value of x?

Comment: I thought x would be the elapsed time? So it is the value of the past seconds !=0 ?

Comment: it does not update x itself. use setOnChronometerTickListener to update its value.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. Is there a bracket mistake in your code? I can't just use it

Comment: mistake is removed now

Comment: Right. It still doesn't work perfect, now it is like refreshing the time everytime the button is clicked

Comment: What are you using it for? Tell more about the context of this code.

Comment: try the above code now. It will reset chronomter when stopped.

Comment: Thank you, it's doing what I want it to!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is this line:

```
long timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - focus.getBase();
```

Since focus variable has not been initialized you get NullPointer.
You should call getBase() after initialization.

Also, you should use ToggleButton instead of Button for this App.

Comment: How do I use a togglebutton? Do I set one condition and it can be retracted after deactivating the button?

Comment: Except for differences in visual representation, toggle button has method 'start.isChecked()' which you can use in your listener to distinguish whether it is on or off.
Where start is the variable of type ToggleButton

Comment: Okay, I tried it. When I uncheck the button, it seems to stop counting, but when I re-check it, you can see, that it just didn't show it counting, but the time went on

Comment: Yes, I noticed that algorithm is wrong. That would be a different question ;)